# Does the timelessness of vacuum follow from the structure of Minkowski spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time

The timelessness, that means the absence of time evolution, of the vacuum between worldlines seems to follow directly from the structure of Minkowski spacetime.

For this purpose, one point $P_1$ in a two-dimensional Minkowski diagram with the Minkowski coordinates $(t_1; x_1)$ which is located on the worldline of a particle, is compared with one vacuum point $P_2$ , that means, a point which is not located on the worldline of a particle, with the Minkowski coordinates $(t_1; x_2)$. For $P_1$ it is possible to define a position for the time $t_1 + dt$, that is after a small time interval. The new position depends on the velocity $v_1$ of the particle, and the new coordinates are $(t_1 + dt; x_1 + v_1 dt)$. The particle follows its worldline.

In contrast, for the vacuum point $P_2$, there is no worldline defining any velocity, and by consequence it is impossible to define any temporal evolution - vacuum is timeless.

Is such a derivation correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tease out what you have in mind here, partly because your terminology is nonstandard.

> The timelessness, that means the absence of time evolution, of the vacuum between worldlines

In more standard terminology, I think the way to say this would be that when there are no matter fields, the spacetime described by SR is homogeneous with respect to timelike translations.

I don't think your explanation of this fact really works. An isolated particle is not a clock. Given any particle that moves inertially, we can choose a frame such that the particle is at rest. The existence of this particle, standing still, doesn't break the homogeneity with respect to translations in the direction parallel to the particle's velocity vector.

It is also possible for spacetime to be inhomogeneous with respect to timelike translations, even if there are no matter fields, because spacetime can have nonzero curvature, as in GR. So the reason that the spacetime of SR is homogeneous with respect to timelike translations, in the absence of matter fields, is that we simply took that as an assumption when we defined what SR was. SR is the special case of GR where spacetime is flat.

Note that even if you do have matter fields, you don't necessarily have clocks. Maxwell's equations are conformally invariant, so basically you can't make a clock out of light.

Comment: The relativity principle of SR prohibits the assumption that the vacuum point $P_2$ will have velocity v=0 and will maintain its space coordinate $x_2$.

Comment: @Moonraker: Is your comment commenting on something in my answer? I don't see a connection. Note that it doesn't really make sense to talk about the velocity of P2, because in your question you've defined P2 as an event. Events don't have velocities.